# Is this relation, linking equivalent interest rates, correct?

Tags: finance, actuarial-science

Within my lecture notes for a previous module on actuarial mathematics, I have written the following relation linking the EPV of an $n$-year term insurance payable at the end of the **month** of death, to the EPV of an $n$-year term insurance payable at the end of the **year** of death:
$$
A_{ \hspace{6mm} x : \overline{n}|}^{(m) \hspace{1mm} 1} = \frac{i}{i^{(m)}} A_{x : \overline{n}|}^1
$$

However, the following screenshot shows part of the solution to a problem which involves making this conversion.

[image: notes]

I am assuming that the term $(1+i)^\frac{11}{24}$ implies that
$$
\frac{i}{i^{(m)}} = (1+i)^\frac{m-1}{2m}
$$

Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note that it has been **years** since I've seen this material, but I believe that the equation you've stated 
$$
A_{ \hspace{6mm} x : \overline{n}|}^{(m) \hspace{1mm} 1} = \frac{i}{i^{(m)}} A_{x : \overline{n}|}^1
$$
is only true under **uniform distribution** of deaths. If memory serves, this entails uniform distribution of deaths within every single year. I believe you should be able to find a proof in *Actuarial Mathematics for Life Contingent Risks*, 2nd edition, by Dickson et al. The slides at http://users.math.msu.edu/users/valdezea/stt455f14/STT455Weeks6to8-F2014.pdf discuss this as well:

[image]

I am not as familiar with the claims acceleration approach, but I believe that the claims acceleration is just an approximation; one should not equate an approximation with an exact result from a different assumption.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not correct. In general, using the actuarial notation, you have:

$(1+i) = (1+\frac{i^{(m)}}{m})^m$, which gives that $ \frac{i}{i^{(m)}} = \frac{i}{m\left((1+i)^{\frac{1}{m}}-1\right)}$.

Comment: For small values of $i \geq 0$, they do seem to be very similar. See here: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/syankzmjm1